# Creating an NFA Diagram where one of the last three chars is an 'a'

Tags: logic, state, automata, dfa, nfa

having some trouble with this question creating an NFA, would appreciate some help

L consists of all words over {a,b}

has an 'a' as one of the last 3 characters in the word

the length of the words can be less than 3

'a' is in the language, while 'bb' is not in the language

Comment: Please say some more about what you have figured out so far and where you have got stuck. As commented many times on this site, this is not a homework solution service.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.....may be helpful......[image]

Comment: Quick notes: 1) this is actually a DFA (not an NFA), 2) You have two q2's, the lower one should probably be q4.